# how to change the opacity of the snackbar in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I wish to change the opacity of the SnackBar. It has only the background property. Can it be customized or I have to create the custom widget for snack bar?

Answer (score 143, accepted):

Try using the color property of snack bar like this,

```
  backgroundColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5)
```

This should work as you expected.

Answer (score 21):

You can adjust the opactiy of your `backgroundColor` with

- `color.withAlpha(..)`,
- `color.withOpacity(..)`,
- using a hexadecimal integer `0x33ffffff` (the first pair of digits after the `x` represents the alpha value),
- creating a `Color` using `Color.fromARGB(...)`
- or by using `Color.fromRGBO(...)`.

You can find information about this on this [documentation page about the `Color` class](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-ui/Color-class.html).

Now, you face the following *problem*: Your content is not yet translucent.

This is easily adjustable using the [`Opcacity`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Opacity-class.html) Widget.

In your `Snackbar` just surround your actual `content` with an `Opacity` Widget:

```
SnackBar(backgroundColor: Color(0x66bbbbbb),
  content: Opacity(opacity: .7,
                    child: Container(), // your content
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are planning to make the background transparent, this may help you.
Mostly you get a black background because of elevation.

```
SnackBar(
  elevation: 0,
  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
  /....... 
),
```

Comment: This is quiet correct for my use case. Elevation leaves a "shade" in the background and setting up elevation to 0 fixes the thing.